# CouchDB Lucene How to URL Encode Query containing Minus (-)

Tags: lucene, couchdb, couchdb-lucene

I'd like to query text containing a minus (-) Sign, e.g.

```
foo-bar
```

with a couchdb lucene fulltext query.
Following lucene rules I'd have to escape the minus, resulting in

```
foo\-bar
```

Last I'd have to urlencode the backslash resulting in

```
foo%5C-bar
```

So the complete url would be:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5984/_fti/local/db/_design/foo/by_subject?q=foo%5C-bar
```

Neither works. The result is always split in two phrases

```
"q":"default:foo default:bar"
```

Leading to documents containing only foo or bar being found also.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escaping the "-" isn't really what you need.  The problem you are running into is that your analyzer tokenizes on the "-", so you are really searching for two different terms.  You need to search for a phrase, instead.  To [search a phrase](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_9_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Terms), just wrap it in quotes:  `"foo-bar"`

or

```
http://127.0.0.1:5984/_fti/local/db/_design/foo/by_subject?q=%22foo-bar%22
```

Comment: You are right! Using you're phrase "foo-bar" gives answer:
    "q":"default:\"foo bar\"" and finds the correct doc. 
Thanks you!